# Different integral notations

Tags: integration, notation

In MS Word there are 2 different integral notations as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

Is there any difference or it is the same?

Comment: Identical meaning.  Form 1 is more common inline in text, e.g., $\int_0^1 x^2 \,\mathrm{d}x$.  Form 2 is more common in a display expression/equation, e.g., $$\int_0^1 x^2 \,\mathrm{d}x \text{.} $$

Comment: They are the same. The small change in the position of the limits makes no difference.

Comment: Why did Microsoft make two of them?

Comment: My guess is that Microsoft thought that style 1  would be better in inline formulas, while style 2 might be wanted in displayed formulas. As @EricTowers' comment shows, the designers of MathJax (and LaTeX) didn't choose to use style 2 in displayed formulas, although they did chose it for summations: $$\sum_a^b x_i$$.